# Why doesn't null evaluate to false?

Tags: c#, null, type-conversion, conditional-statements

What is the reason `null` doesn't evaluate to `false` in conditionals?

I first thought about assignments to avoid the bug of using `=` instead of `==`, but this could easily be disallowed by the compiler.

```
if (someClass = someValue) // cannot convert someClass to bool. Ok, nice

if (someClass) // Cannot convert someClass to bool. Why?

if (someClass != null) // More readable?
```

I think it's fairly reasonable to assume that `null` means `false`. There are other languages that use this too, and I've not had a bug because of it.

**Edit:** And I'm of course referring to reference types.

A good comment by Daniel Earwicker on the assignment bug... This compiles without a warning because it evaluates to `bool`:

```
bool bool1 = false, bool2 = true;
if (bool1 = bool2)
{
    // oops... false == true, and bool1 became true...
}
```

Comment: The simple response is: "That's how the C# designers wanted it." Yet that doesn't really answer the question.  Does anyone have insight into why the language designers didn't like automatically casting references to booleans (like C/C++/Python)?

Comment: I'm trying to track down a reference - I think I got it from speaking to one of the language team a while back, which doesn't really help

Comment: I think only C programmers would think it reasonable that null means false.  False is a value, null is lack of a value.  C# gets it right I think. Other languages that were built without a boolean type or a concept of a pointer (or nullable type) just overloaded an int to mean all these different things.  Why should NULL==false and false==0 ? They shouldn't.

Comment: It would be nice for pragmatism. For example, [in ruby you can safe validate a null instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088533/rubys-or-equals-in-javascript) with just 3 tokens like this: `obj ||= ClassName.new`. In c# you are forced to do an if validation: `obj is null ? new ClassName() : obj` which is not sexy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a specific design feature in the C# language: [`if` statements accept only a `bool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx).

IIRC this is for safety: specifically, so that your first `if (someClass = someValue)` fails to compile.

**Edit:** One benefit is that it makes the `if (42 == i)` convention ("yoda comparisons") unnecessary.

Comment: But instead of saying "only accepts bool" it could say "does not accept assignment"...

Comment: Yeah, I find C#'s behavior preferable here, specifically because it protects you from that common bug

Comment: Assignment-as-condition is useful, albeit not so much in `if` statements: `while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)`

Comment: The `if (a = b)` bug is not stopped by this, because `a` and `b` may be of type `bool`.

Comment: @simendsjo Except that you can assign in that expression, so it would assign first and then attempt to implicitly convert the object to a bool and would then (usually) fail.

Comment: This is really terrible behaviour. I get that null isn't a value but an if statement should accept a single reference and if that is not a value do the same thing as would happen when evaluated to false.

Answer (score 22):

"I think it's fairly reasonable to assume that null means false"

Not in C#. false is a boolean struct, a value type. Value types cannot have a null value.  If you wanted to do what you achieved, you'd have to create custom converters of your particular type to boolean:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static implicit operator bool(MyClass instance)
    {
        return instance != null;
    }
}
```

With the above, I could then do:

```
if (instance) {

}
```

etc.

Comment: You could also use the true or false operators, though they're a tad obscure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: On a side note, an interesting consequence of using the true and false operators is that a particular state could be true, false, neither or both.  This means a type implementing the true and false operators could satisfy the expression `Debug.Assert(x && !x)`

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I have a status object, and I wanted to be able to do `if (status) {}` instead of `if (status.isSuccess()){}`. I'm still not sure if it's a good idea, but now I now I can do it.

Answer (score 14):

"I think it's fairly reasonable to assume that null means false"

I don't agree. IMHO, more often than not, false means "no". Null means "I don't know"; i.e. completely indeterminate.

Comment: +1 - does NULL *ever* mean false?  I can't think of any examples of a technology that is implemented this way.  There may be some that implicitly allow comparisons, but afaik, null never means false.

Comment: While I'm not an expert on many different languages, I think NULL probably only ever "means" false in a language that doesn't properly handle NULL in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

One thing that comes to mind what about in the instance of a data type, like int?  Int's can't be null, so do they always evaluate to true?  You could assume that int = 0 is false, but that starts to get really complicated, because 0 is a valid value (where maybe 0 should evaluate to true, because the progammer set it) and not just a default value.
There are a lot of edge cases where null isn't an option, or sometimes it's an option, and other times it's not.

They put in things like this to protect the programmer from making mistakes.  It goes along the same line of why you can't do fall through in case statements.

Comment: +1

NULL means that value is unknown or value is missing or value hasn't been assigned yet etc. it doesn't mean FALSE, semantically they are not the same. I always think treating NULL as FALSE is a bad language design.

Comment: @Liwen I agree.  On the surface, it seems like it could make sense, but there are just too many possibilities where null and false will differ.

Comment: But a valuetype is not a reference type and cannot be null. I'm not saying that every possible type other than false should evaluate to true...

Comment: Right, but that is what I'm saying.  if(object) does an evaluation as to if it's null, what are the rules around something which can't be null? It just gets really harry around the rules of making an assumption as to what you want to evaluate in an if(object) scenario.

Answer (score 5):

Just use if(Convert.ToBoolean(someClass))

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd.aspx

> Parameters
>
> value Type: System.Object An object that implements the
>   IConvertible interface, or null. 
>   Return Value
>
> Type: System.Boolean true or false,
>   which reflects the value returned by
>   invoking the IConvertible.ToBoolean
>   method for the underlying type of
>   value.  If value is null, the method
>   returns false

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, this is a feature that you see in dynamic languages, which C# is not (per the language specification `if` only accepts `bool` or an expression that evaluates to `bool`).

I don't think it's reasonable to assume that `null` is `false` in *every* case. It makes sense in some cases, but not in others. For example, assume that you have a flag that can have three values: *set*, *unset*, and *un-initialized*. In this case, *set* would be `true`, *unset* would be `false` and *un-initialized* would be `null`. As you can see, in this case the meaning of `null` is not `false`.

Comment: Losely typed ≠ dynamically typed.  C++ evaluates `NULL` (a macro) to `0` which then evaluates to `false` in the `if` statement.

Comment: I wasn't talking about `NULL`. I was talking about `null`. I don't see how my original statement is wrong. You normally do see `if(someVarThatCouldBeNull)` in dynamic languages.

Comment: I agree, Vivin.  I would say that the concept of null does not exist in C++.  Or rather, the concept of a variable with no value (i.e. null in C#) does not exist in C++.  A variable will always have a value, you just don't know what it is unless you initialize it yourself.  As strager points out, NULL in C++ is just a macro to represent 0, nothing more.  There are no special compiler rules around it.

Comment: @Dr. Wily's Apprentice. I was trying to say the same thing :) Thanks for explaining it though. I also was not sure why strager was talking about C++ - the question is about C#?

Answer (score 3):

Because null and false are different things.

A perfect example is bool? foo

If foo's value is true, then its value is true.
If foo's value is false, then its value is false
If foo has nothing assigned to it, its value is null.

These are three logically separate conditions.

Think of it another way
"**How much money do I owe you?**"
"*Nothing*" and "*I don't have that information*"  are two distinctly separate answers.

Comment: +1 for good point, but still.. If you try to evaluate a bool? you either has to cast it to a bool and potentionally get a runtime error, or use == true / false to evaluate it... bool? is not a reference type as my question, it's still a valuetype

Comment: As a side note, a computer is supposed to know answers for questions about data, and should probably signal an error if something "cannot be determined".

Answer (score 3):

> What is the reason null doesn't
>   evaluate to false in conditionals?
>
> I first thought about assignments to
>   avoid the bug of using `=` instead of
>   `==`

That isn't the reason. We know this because if the two variables being compared happen to be of type `bool` then the code will compile quite happily:

```
bool a = ...
bool b = ...

if (a = b)
    Console.WriteLine("Weird, I expected them to be different");
```

If `b` is true, the message is printed (and `a` is now true, making the subsequent debugging experience consistent with the message, thus confusing you even more...)

The reason `null` is not convertible to `bool` is simply that C# avoids implicit conversion unless requested by the designer of a user-defined type. The C++ history book is full of painful stories caused by implicit conversions.

Comment: I already updated my question with this from your previous comment. The implicit conversion argument is the best I've hear so far.

Answer (score 3):

Structurally, most people who "cannot think of any technological reason null should be equal to false" get it wrong.

Code is run by CPUs.
Most (if not all) CPUs have **bits**, **groups of bits** and **interpretations of groups of bits**. That said, something can be `0`, `1`, a `byte`, a `word`, a `dword`, a `qword` and so on.

Note that on x86 platform, bytes are octets (8 bits), and words are usually 16 bits, but this is not a necessity. Older CPUs had words of 4 bits, and even todays' low-end embedded controllers often use like 7 or 12 bits per word.

That said, something is either "equal", "zero", "greater", "less", "greater or equal", or "less or equal" in machine code. There is no such thing as `null`, `false` or `true`.

As a convention, `true` is `1`, `false` is `0`, and a `null` pointer is either `0x00`, `0x0000`, `0x00000000`, or `0x0000000000000000`, depending on *address bus* width.

C# is one of the exceptions, as it is an indirect type, where the two possible values `0` and `1` are not an immediate value, but an **index** of a structure (think `enum` in C, or `PTR` in x86 assembly).

This is by design.

It is important to note, though, that such design decisions are **elaborate** decisions, while the **traditional, straightforward** way is to assume that `0`, `null` and `false` are equal.

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't make a conversion of the parameter, as C++ does. You need to explicitly convert the value in a boolean, if you want the `if` statement to accept the value.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply the type system of c# compared to languages like PHP, Perl, etc.

A condition only accepts `Boolean` values, null does not have the type `Boolean` so it doesn't work there.

As for the NULL example in C/C++ you mentioned in another comment it has to be said that neither C nor C++ have a boolean type (afair C++ usually has a typecast for bool that resolves to an int, but thats another matter) and they also have no null-references, only NULL(=> 0)-pointers.

Of course the compiler designers could implement an automatic conversion for any nullable type to boolean but that would cause other problems, i.e.:

Assuming that `foo` is *not* `null`:

```
if (foo)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Which state of foo is true?
Always if it's not null?
But what if you want your type to be convertable to boolean (i.e. from your tri-state or quantum-logic class)?

That would mean you would have two different conversions to bool, the implicit and the explicit, which would both behave differently.

I don't even dare to imagine what should happen if you do

```
if (!!foo) // common pattern in C to normalize a value used as boolean,
           // in this case might be abused to create a boolean from an object
{
}
```

I think the forced `(foo == null)` is good since it also adds clarity to your code, it's easier to understand what you really check for.