# Ruby's ||= (or equals) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, syntax

I love Ruby's `||=` mechanism. If a variable doesn't exist or is `nil`, then create it and set it equal to something:

```
amount # is nil
amount ||= 0 # is 0
amount ||= 5 # is 0
```

I need to do something similar in JavaScript now. What's the convention or proper way to do this? I know `||=` is not valid syntax. 2 obvious ways to handle it are:

```
window.myLib = window.myLib || {};

// or

if (!window.myLib)
  window.myLib = {};
```

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Both are absolutely correct, but if you are looking for something that works like `||=` in ruby. The first method which is `variable = variable || {}` is the one you are looking for :)

Comment: Careful using this if a valid value for `x` is falsy, like `false`, and you only want to set a default when `x` is undefined.

Comment: above comment is right. Taking your example case , it will not work the same way in JS.
`let amount = 0;` followed by `amount = amount || 5`  will change amount to 5. If you dont want that to happen use `??` operator instead of `||` .

Comment: @AshwinKumarS Or just use `amount ??= 5;`.

Comment: @user4642212 I dont think that syntax works in JS, does it ?

Comment: @AshwinKumarS Yes, it does. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment/).

Comment: @user4642212 interesting, i tried to run the demo there in docs page but got an error `Error: Unexpected token '='`

Comment: @AshwinKumarS The documentation link includes a browser compatibility table.

Comment: @user4642212 geez bummer. thanks...sadly doesn't work with node as well..for now.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the logical OR operator `||` which evaluates its right operand if `lVal` is a falsy value.

Falsy values include e.g `null, false, 0, "", undefined, NaN`

```
x = x || 1
```

Comment: Careful using this if a valid value for `x` is falsy, like `false`, and you only want to set a default when `x` is undefined.

Answer (score 11):

The operator you asked about [has been proposed as a feature in JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment). It is currently at [Stage 4](https://tc39.es/process-document/), and it will be [introduced in the next ECMAScript standard](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md), which is expected to be published in 2021.

You can use it now using [the plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators). I have never used that plugin, so I have no idea how well it works.

Comment: Update: the proposal is now [finished](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md), i.e. it has reached Stage 4 and is included in the latest draft of the ECMAScript specification. It will be included in the next standard, which will be published in 2021.

Comment: We be living in the future now. Answer should be updated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment or I guess scrolling down someone has added other answers at least

Answer (score 5):

If you're working with objects, you can use destructuring (since ES6) like so:

```
({ myLib: window.myLib = {} } = window);
```

...but you don't gain anything over the accepted answer except confusion.

Comment: "but you don't gain anything over the accepted answer except confusion" -- nice. :)

Comment: I bet somebody is gonna take this as a reason to hate javascript

Answer (score 5):

As of 2021, you can use `||=` with identical behavior to Ruby as long as you are transpiling or don't care about Opera/IE.

Logical OR assignement, `||=` is now supported natively in javascript on all major browsers except Opera and IE. [Current caniuse matrix](https://caniuse.com/?search=logical%20assignment). [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment).

Typescript added support for the operator in [version 4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#short-circuiting-assignment-operators). If you need to support IE/Opera you can use the [babel plugin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#short-circuiting-assignment-operators) to transpile for broad compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

### Logical nullish assignment (??=)

```js
x ??= 23
```

[Documentation & Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Answer (score -1):

Ruby's ||= operator short circuits assignment.  It can be thought of like this:

```
return a || a = b
```

So in javascript, this looks very similar:

```
return a || (a = b);
```

It seems as pointed out in the comments below however, that this literal ruby form is less efficient than the standard javascript idiom a = a || b.

For reference:
http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html

Comment: In practice it seems that the `a = a || b` form is more optimal http://jsperf.com/x-or-x-equals-0-vs-x-equals-x-or-0/3

Comment: ah cool tool.  what does it look like if x has a value and so short circuits?

Comment: I believe teardown needs to be explicit on jsperf so [this test](http://jsperf.com/x-or-x-equals-0-vs-x-equals-x-or-0/4) should show the short circuit performance. My guess is that V8 has a special optimization for the form `a = a || b`.

Comment: FYI It looks like whatever difference there was has now been optimized away.

Comment: `a || (a = b)` has the correct semantics to infer function names. It’s currently under [discussion](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment/issues/23) for the new proposal.

Comment: UPDATE: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the desired behaviour using |= operator in javascript for integers only. But you have to define the variable first.

```
let a = 0
a |= 100
console.log(a) // 100
```

For objects

```
let o = {}
o.a |= 100
console.log(o) // {a: 100}
```

For Arrays

```
let arr = []
arr[0] |= 100
console.log(arr) // [100]
```

Comment: The question isn’t about `|` or `|=`. The desired behavior in the question is unrelated to bitwise operations.

Comment: Edited. I hope it makes sense now.